# Checking to see if the value is less than or equal to the value before it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set consisting of 20 numbers. I am trying to create an if statement that if the number is less than or equal to the number before it, to stop and take an average then continue the process until it reaches the end of the data set.
A snippet:

```
2
3
4
5
5
6
7
8
8
```

I want it to print out:
3.5 , 7

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if (df.loc[i, 'list1'] <= df.loc[i, 'list1' - 1]):

       res = []
       res.append(sum(df["list1"]   [i:i+len(df['list1'])]) / len(df['list1']))
```

Comment: It's not clear what's being averaged. *All* your numbers are less than or equal to its preceding neighbor.

Comment: @chepner they are bigger or equal.

Comment: @chepner 5 is less or equal to 5.

Comment: Right, I had my directions confused. But the question stands: what exactly is being averaged? `2,3,4,5` and `6,7,8`?

Comment: @Amber can you explain where does `7` come from? 3.5 would be an average of 2, 3, 4 and 5, but according to that logic you should have 5, 6, 7, 8 averaging to 6.5. Or do you ignore the number that broke the ascending order?

Comment: Sorry, if the value is equal to or less than the one before it, I want that value to be disregarded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None, names=['values'])

df['grp'] = (df['values'].diff() == 0).cumsum()

df.drop_duplicates('values', keep='first').groupby('grp').mean()
```

Output:

```
     values
grp        
0       3.5
1       7.0
```